# AdContol auto colapses

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

I use AdControl in WP8. When AdControl responses error, invoke event ErrorOccurred and AdControl colapses itself. But I need that AdControl still be visible and hold place on Grid. I try to set IsAutoCollapseEnabled = false, but it doesn't help! 
What have I do to make AdControl be visible all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a placeholder grid that has a rectangle or empty textblock that the adcontrol sits in with a static size by setting the height and width of the adcontrol so if it collapses, you still retain the layout? Like so:

```
<Grid Width="480" Height="80">
   <TextBlock Width="480" Height="80"/>
   <AdControl/>
</Grid>`
```

T.J. Mullen
http://www.tjmullenpresents.com